# Fork/Join framework for quicksort execute longer than normal quicksort

Tags: java, fork-join

i wrote fork/join quick sort and normal quick sort in one class and then I counted the time of execute both. Weird is that fork/join works longer then normal quick sort. The question is why?

### Main

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(50000);

    for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i ++)
    {
        list.add(generator.nextInt(500200));
    }


   List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list);





    ConcurrentQuickSort<Integer> sort = new ConcurrentQuickSort<>(list,0,list.size() - 1);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    pool.invoke(sort);
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ConcurrentTime = (endTime - startTime);


    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ConcurrentQuickSort<Integer> sort2 = new ConcurrentQuickSort<>(list2,0,list.size() - 1);
    sort2.doSort(0,list2.size() - 1);
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long sequentialTime = (endTime - startTime);


    System.out.println(ConcurrentTime);
    System.out.println(sequentialTime);
    System.out.println(sort2.isCorrect(list));

   }
}
```

### ConcurrentQuickSort

```
public class ConcurrentQuickSort<T extends Comparable<T> > extends RecursiveAction
{
    private List<T> list;
    private int size;
    private int begin;
    private int end;


public ConcurrentQuickSort(List<T> list,int begin,int end)
{
    this.list = list;
    this.size = this.list.size();
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;

}


private int partition(int begin, int end)
{

    T x = list.get(begin);
    int i = begin;
    int j = end;

    while(true)
    {
        while(list.get(j).compareTo(x) > 0)
        {
            j--;
        }

        while(list.get(i).compareTo(x) < 0)
        {
            i++;
        }

        if(i < j)
        {
            swap(i,j);
            i++;
            j--;

        }
        else
            return j;
    }
}

public void doSort(int begin, int end)
{
    int q;
    if(begin < end)
     {
        q = partition(begin,end);

         doSort(begin,q);
         doSort(q + 1,end);
    }
}

public void doSort()
{

}

public void sort()
{
    doSort(0,list.size() - 1);
}

private void swap(int first, int second)
{
    T temp = list.get(first);
    list.set(first,list.get(second));
    list.set(second,temp);
}

@Override
protected void compute()
{

    int q;
    if(begin < end)
    {

        q = partition(begin,end);
        List<ConcurrentQuickSort<T>> subtasks = splitWork(q);
        for(ConcurrentQuickSort<T> t : subtasks)
        {
            t.fork();
        }


    }
}

private List<ConcurrentQuickSort<T>> splitWork(int q)
{
    List<ConcurrentQuickSort<T>> subtasks = new ArrayList<>();
    subtasks.add(new ConcurrentQuickSort<>(this.list,begin,q));
    subtasks.add(new ConcurrentQuickSort<>(this.list,q +1,end));
    return subtasks;
}

public boolean isCorrect(List<T> other)
{
   return list.equals(other);
}
 }
```

Time of execute normal quicksort is like 20 miliseconds and fork/join 80. Why?

Comment: is it correct though?

Comment: Yee i think so, both lists are the same after both sort, check by method "isCorrect"

Comment: Concurrency can have significant overhead by itself, especially on a per-task basis.  To get actual performance wins, concurrency has to be used relatively sparingly at a high level, especially not splitting off very small tasks.  This result isn't actually surprising.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so is there any possibly case in sorting when concurrency help significantly decrease execution time?

Comment: @PassMan Possibly, but you don't want to split the array up further than a relatively large threshold.  [`Arrays.parallelSort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-int:A-) does the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small enough datasets:

- The cost of synchronizing data between different threads will exceed the benefit of parallelism
- Several threads will work on ranges of memory so close to each other, that it will be cached in the L1 cache of each core, which means less efficient use of cache (the same data is fetched from memory several times when it was actually in the cache of another core)
- Bubblesort will actually outperform quicksort because even though O(n^2) > O(n log n), the cost of making recursive calls will exceed the extra O-complexity of bubblesort

If you implement a lower threshold where you switch between concurrent and non-concurrent quicksort and between quicksort and bubblesort you might be able to work out the line size and algoritm of the different cpu-caches.

The javadoc for [RecursiveAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) shows an implementation of merge sort with the threshold set at 1000.